# $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] not equal to real server ip address

Tags: php

I am working on a dedicated server, yet the IP address returns by `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` is different from the real IP address of the server.

Would you happen to know how this is possible? Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for `REMOTE_ADDR`?

Comment: Are both ipaddresses in the same format ? (IPv4 / IPv6)

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Examples: proxy server/NAT/frontend-backend division/...

Comment: Just an example, if you had multiple computers behind a router, all the computers would have different IP address's but they would all have the same external (Gateway) IP address.

Comment: Thank you Alma Do and Pwner, that makes sense

Answer (score 3):

you can use,

```
gethostbyname($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])
```

or

```
getHostByName(php_uname('n'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using,

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']
```

reference [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For)

Comment: He isn't asking for the *client* address. He clearly states *server* in the question.